# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel - Convert .xlsx to .csv with UTF-8 Encoding in vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-interop

Currently I'm try to convert .xlsx (there is only one sheet) to .csv with UTF-8 Encoding.

```
Dim excelApplication As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook

excelApplication = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
workbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(in_InputFilePath)

excelApplication.Visible = False
excelApplication.DisplayAlerts = False
workbook.SaveAs(in_OutputFilePath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV)
excelApplication.DisplayAlerts = True
excelApplication.Visible = True

workbook.Close()
```

However, there is no CSV UTF-8 for XlFileFormat https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat?view=excel-pia
Could you help to suggest me, please?

Comment: `XlFileFormat.xlCSVUTF8`

Comment: @Jimi, thank you, but there is no XlFileFormat.xlCSVUTF8 as the reference above.

Comment: Maybe they forgot about it? Its value is `62`. Try to cast it. To note that `XlFileFormat.xlCSVUTF8` is related to VBA, not exactly Interop, but it should be the same. It's also to note that Excel has a *thing* for the Local Encoding (or the language used when the application was installed). It may refuse to use a different Encoding (in VBA, it defaults to `en-US`).

Comment: @Jimi, It's working https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat, OK, thank you very much. Could you help to post the answer again, please? I will mark it correct for helping another people in the future.

Comment: The option is supported, but as of Excel `16.0.7466.2023` (2016). Earlier versions don't allow to use that value (neither `[Workbook].WebOptions.Encoding = MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8`, this will also use the CodePage of the Language used for the installation, not other languages added later, even if set as default). Thus, if you actually need to use Interop, you may find machines where Excel is not updated or older, ruining it all. Another option is to use EPPlus (ver. `< 5.0`) or OleDb (maybe adding `CSVHelper`).